# Basecamp Trix Editor loading stored content from JSON

Tags: trix

I have Trix data that I saved by doing `element.editor.getDocument()`. Is there a way to load this data into the trix editor?

It seems like the only way to load data is to take the actually HTML values like so which isn't really helpful:

```
<input id="chatInput" type="hidden" name="content" value="<div>This is a test attachment&amp;nbsp;<figure data-trix-attachment=&quot;{&amp;quot;content&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;<span class='mention'>@Bryan</span>&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;uid&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;1&amp;quot;}&quot; data-trix-content-type=&quot;undefined&quot; class=&quot;attachment attachment--content&quot;><span class=&quot;mention&quot;>@Bryan</span><figcaption class=&quot;attachment__caption&quot;></figcaption></figure></div>">
```

### What the data looks like:

```
[{"text":[{"type":"string","attributes":{},"string":"This is a test attachment "},{"type":"attachment","attributes":{},"attachment":{"content":"<span class='mention'>@Bryan</span>","uid":"1"}},{"type":"string","attributes":{},"string":" "},{"type":"string","attributes":{"blockBreak":true},"string":"\n"}],"attributes":[]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the [documentation](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/blob/master/src/trix/models/editor.coffee), I found out that you do it like so:

```
editor.loadJSON({document: "{}"})
```

Comment: You and I have very different opinions on what constitutes "documentation". To me that was more like reading the source code.

Comment: I had my JSON string in a variable named "content". This finally worked after I realized that I had to include the inner part of the parenthesis. This is the actual working code: 

`trix_object.editor.loadJSON({document: content});`